# Possible to use an object property as a method's argument

Tags: javascript, class, object

Basically I am trying to create an object property that will dynamically create an array based on the constructor. The following works if I remove the constructor and simply set testArray.length to some integer. But stops working when I try setting length with a constructor.

```js
class TestArray {
  constructor(length) {
    this.length = length;
  }

  buildArray = function(length) {
    let array = [];
    for (let i = length; i > 0; i--) {
      array.push("_");
    }
    return array;
  }

  array = this.buildArray(this.length);
}

let testArray = new TestArray(2);
console.log(testArray.array);


let testArray2 = new TestArray(2);
console.log(testArray2.array);

//[] is logged. Desired out put is ['_', '_']
```

Do I have syntax issue or a logic issue?  Is there a plain better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class fields - assignments directly inside a class body - run *before* the body of the constructor runs (assuming there's no superclass). Your code is equivalent to

```
class TestArray {
  constructor(length){
    array = this.buildArray(this.length);
    this.length = length;
  }
```

See the problem? `this.length` hasn't been assigned to at the time you call `buildArray`, so it's `undefined`.

Remove the class field, and put that logic in the constructor, so that you can make use of the constructor's argument. Might as well ditch `this.length` entirely at that point too, it doesn't look to be doing anything useful.

```js
class TestArray {
  constructor(length){
    this.array = this.buildArray(length);
  }
  buildArray = function(length){
      let array = [];
      for(let i = length ; i > 0; i--){
          array.push("_");
      }
      return array;
  }
}

let testArray = new TestArray(2);
console.log(testArray.array);
```

Comment: Wow I did not realize that! Makes perfect sense now. I had tried using the function in the constructor, but I was doing it wrong because I didn't understand the order that things was happening. Thanks!